# Track dynamic sub domains in analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, web-analytics

Whenever any clients sign-up with our web app, a new sub-domain will be created automatically e.g. a.myapp.com, b.myapp.com, ab.myapp.com, aa.myapp.com, etc.

1. I want to track which sub-domain is being visited the most, so I want to track all the sub-domains withing single profile (sub-domain traffic only), excluding main domain's (myapp.com) traffic. However, I need to filter all internal (for testing) sub-domains like test.myapp.com, dev.myapp.com, etc. all test sub-domains start with test, dev or staging, but the list is huge so not possible to exclude them manually (my main domain runs without "www").
   And, I should also be able to see the full URLs so that I could identify between all sub-domains.
2. 2nd profile is created for main domain traffic only (without "www"), so all sub-domain traffic needs to be filtered including internal (testing sub-domains)

Please help!

Comment: Do you want to create a profile/view for each newly created subdomain (that would exhaust the quota for available view pretty quick) or are you just looking for a way to create a look of filters at one time ?

Comment: No, there will a single profile and want to see full URL path for each domain to differentiate traffic. As I'll be having 1000s of dynamically generated sub-domains, so it is practically not possible to create profile/view for each sub-domain.

Answer (score 2):

Google recommends [using a custom filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en) if you want to see the entire URL in reports, and not just the path.  You just need to set up the two profiles (Main Site and All Subdomains) and then add the following filters to each:

### Main Site:

You just need a filter excluding everything except the http://domain.com hostname:

- **Filter Type:** Custom filter > Exclude
- **Filter Field:** Hostname
- **Filter Pattern:** ..*.domain.com   *- this regex looks for anything.domain.com*

### All Other Subdomains:

*You need two filters, one to exclude main site traffic, one to add the subdomains to the path in reports*

#### Exclude main domain:

- **Filter Type:** Custom filter > Exclude
- **Filter Field:** Hostname
- **Filter Pattern:** ^domain.com   *- this regex looks for just domain.com*

#### Add subdomain to URL Path:

- **Filter Type:** Custom filter > Advanced
- **Field A:** Hostname
- **Extract A:** (.*)
- **Field B:** Request URI
- **Extract B:** (.*)
- **Output To:** Request URI
- **Constructor:** $A1$B1

Comment: In all honesty, you have this built into the Analytics suite. If you access the Hostname report, you'll see all the hostnames which trigger your session information. 

Audience -> Technology -> Network -> Hostname

Using the above suggestion will return zero data as you are excluding all traffic to your domain and then try to include traffic that has already been included.

Comment: @MrSponge - Take a closer look at the regex patterns: **..*.domain.com**  doesn't match on http://domain.com (@Raj mentioned he used that style for his main domain)  And **^domain.com** *only* matches domain.com

Comment: @Andy H: Hmm... Yes, sorry about that. I read it a bit too hastily I believe. That regex should work.

Comment: Thank you all. I have applied it same the way, now waiting for the data to be populated.

Comment: One more thing - How can I exclude my internal test sub-domains from the profile for sub-domains traffic only. Manually is not an option as the list is huge. But starts with staging, dev and test only.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is to use a Custom Dimension (scoped to "Hit") with the subdomain string. Then, you will see page data on all subdomains and can filter as needed (either for a specific subdomain, or to filter out all subdomains).

Doing this would be relatively easy, too. Just modify your Google Analytics snippet in your head to be along the lines of this:

```
<script>
var url = window.location.host.split('.');

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga("set", 'dimension1', url[0]); //Update 'dimension1' to match yours!
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

If you have the subdomain stored somewhere server-side, you could dynamically include it in the snippet above instead of trying to detect it after the fact.

[More information about Custom Dimensions in Google Analytics here.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, let me try this. I think it should solve my problem